# add different characters to a NSString one by one?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

i am retrieving different characters from a string by using thsi function and adding 5 to them to display the corresponding character for eg. 'a' displays 'f' and 'h' displays 'm'..
but the problem is that i am not able to add these characters into a string which i can use to display to display like 'fm'...can anyone help?? heres the code
strResult(mutablestring) is getting null only.

```
str=@"John";

int a=[str length];

for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
  char ch=[str characterAtIndex:i];
  ch=ch+5;
  temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",ch];
  [strResult appendString:temp];
  NSLog(@"%c",ch);
}
```

Comment: How strResult is defined, have you initialized it somewhere?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, you need to make sure you allocate the string `strResult`, like so:

```
NSMutableString *strResult = [NSMutableString string];
```

Second; you can, and indeed should, use `-appendFormat:` for adding the characters to the string; the temporary extra string is pretty useless.

What you want then:

```
NSString *str = @"abcdef";
NSMutableString *strResult = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [str length]; i++) {
  char ch = [str characterAtIndex:i] + 5;
  NSLog(@"%c", ch);
  [strResult appendFormat:@"%c", ch];
}
NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
```

This should produce:

```
f
g
h
i
j
k
fghijk
```